# How do I pronounce 's' in 'shows'?

Tags: pronunciation

In **The chart shows information**, should I pronounce [s] or [z] at the end of ***shows***?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Why are there three pronunciations for the plural "-s"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/268677/why-are-there-three-pronunciations-for-the-plural-s)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rule for the pronunciation of third person S is as follows:

- If the word ends in a sibilant /s, z, ʃ, ʒ, tʃ, dʒ/, then add **/ɪz/**

If the word ends with a different sound, then:

- If the last sound in the base is voiced, add **/z/**
- If the last sound in the base word is voiceless, add **/s/**

The word *show* ends in a vowel sound. Vowel sounds in English are voiced, so we need to add /z/ here: **/ʃəʊz/**.

Comment: Any chance you could add some examples for those of us unfamiliar with the notation and terminology?  Thanks.

Comment: @fixer1234 I'll try to tomorrow, if I get time. Until then [this post on voiced and voiceless sounds might be helpful, ... I hope!](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/285682/detecting-vibration-in-voiced-and-voiceless-english-sounds/285773#285773)