# Is the possessive 's pronounced s or z?

Tags: pronunciation, spoken-english, possessives

Is **'s** as a possessive pronounced as /s/ or /z/ at the end of words? Such as in "Muhammad's house".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are there three pronunciations for the plural "-s"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/268677/why-are-there-three-pronunciations-for-the-plural-s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plural and genitive suffix /z/ is subject to **voicing assimilation**, meaning that the voicing of the suffix is dependent on the sound that precedes it: When the preceding sound is voiceless, the suffix must be the **voiceless** fricative /s/. When the preceding sound is voiced, the suffix must be the **voiced** fricative /z/.

Therefore, **the genitive suffix in *Muhammad's* is /z/** since the preceding consonant is the voiced alveolar stop /d/. One exception to this rule is when the preceding consonant is a sibilant (ie. a fricative or an affricate). In that case, the alternant has to be /ɪz/: eg. "misses" /mɪsɪz/.